# Sharepoint RichImageField set default image

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-branding

In my custom page layout I declare a RichImageField

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichImageField id="InteriorHeaderImage" FieldName="InteriorHeaderImage" InputFieldLabel="Header Image"  runat="server" DisplayWidth="960" DisplayHeight="242"  />
```

I'm trying to figure out how to set the default image so the control always shows an image even the first time a page is created using the layout.

Ideally, I would like a declarative approach for example:

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichImageField id="InteriorHeaderImage" DefaultImageURL="[it should be this easy]" />
```

It appears that the value property of the control is assigned an ImageFieldValue object which I could probably figure out how to set in a code-behind but this approach seems harder than it should be:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.fields.imagefieldvalue.aspx

Solution:
I finally ended up creating a code behind for my page layout by creating a class file that inherits from Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingLayoutPage as described here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb986729.aspx

The code of course ended up only being a couple of lines:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ImageFieldValue imageField = InteriorHeaderImage.Value as ImageFieldValue;
            if (imageField!=null)
            {
                if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageField.ImageUrl))
                    imageField.ImageUrl = "/Style Library/assets/images/img1small.jpg";
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this out at the moment, but the `RichImageField` field control has a [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.richimagefield.value.aspx) property that can be set. Can you try setting this declaratively?

Maybe this will work?:

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichImageField id="InteriorHeaderImage" Value="[it should be this easy]" />
```

Alternatively, you could set in the code-behind for the page layout which should be easier than manipulating the `ImageFieldValue` (as per your link).

Comment: I appreciate your input.  I tested your idea, but as expected the value property doesn't expects a string that represents an ImageFieldValue object. I received the following exception:
Cannot create an object of type 'System.Object' from its string representation 'test.png' for the 'Value' property.

Answer (score 0):

The ImageFieldValue inherits from the HtmlTagValue class. The ImageFieldValue has a constructor that accepts the complete <img /> element. Have you tried setting the default value using the complete <img /> element, like <img src="test.png" />?

Comment: Good idea, I tried your idea without any luck unfortunately.  I think I'll have to try the code-behind approach.

Answer (score 0):

Could you create an `ImageFieldValue` inline?

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichImageField id="InteriorHeaderImage" runat="server"
    DefaultImageURL='<%# new ImageFieldValue("<img src=\"test.png\" />") %>' />
```

This would only work if the control's `DataBind()` method is called at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need and ended up creating a custom control that would add the placeholder/default image to the control on prerender. The custom control is then added right next to the RichImageField control in the page layout.

**Code:**

```
        if ((PublishingPage.IsPublishingPage(SPContext.Current.ListItem)) &&
            (SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode == SPControlMode.Edit || SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode == SPControlMode.New))
        {
            RichImageField image = (RichImageField)this.Parent.FindControl("rifPageImage");
            if (image != null)
            {
                ImageFieldValue imgValue = (ImageFieldValue)image.Value;
                if (imgValue.ImageUrl == string.Empty)
                {
                    image.Value = new ImageFieldValue("<img src='/_layouts/images/GD/placeholder.png' />");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried supplying a default value for your field when you provision your layout into the masterpage gallery?

```
<Property Name="RichImageFieldName" Value="<![CDATA[<IMG SRC="images/pathtoimage.jpg"></IMG>]]>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Andro Selva was correct but i have to revise the code a little bit.  Since my Code Behind is custom as well, instead of using:

```
RichImageField image = (RichImageField)this.Parent.FindControl("rifPageImage");
```

I used:

```
Protected RichImageField rifPageImage;
```

and I just replaced all image to rifPageImage.  I was getting a null value for this.Parent.FindControl since the .cs file is not really linked to my .aspx file.